# UINavigationController not showing

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Have your encounter this issue, the UInavigationController is not showing.. here's my code..

```
eSigHomeViewController *controller = [[eSigHomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"eSigHomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Override point for customization after application launch.
[self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Do, i missed something.. Hope you can provide some assistance..

Thanks,

Nestea

Comment: Class names that begin with a lowercase letter? No thanks.

Comment: Yes, you better stick with Objective-C naming conventions - class names should start with uppercase letter and be AllCamelCased.

Comment: Try logging controller and self.navigationController after you create them to make sure neither is nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this line `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` if you want to see navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're missing

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Comment: Nope. `addSubview:` is just fine as long as the view controller is alive.